# Generate DynamicMethod from MethodInfo

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, methods

I was going over a Joel Pobar's [Dodge Common Performance Pitfalls to Craft Speedy Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163759.aspx) article on Reflection and I was looking at a particular piece of code that isn't compiling (slightly modified to narrow down to the specific error, because his example had more errors):

```
MethodInfo writeLine = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine");
RuntimeMethodHandle myMethodHandle = writeLine.MethodHandle;
DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod(
    "HelloWorld",          // name of the method
    typeof(void),          // return type of the method
    new Type[]{},          // argument types for the method
    false);                // skip JIT visibility checks

ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello, world");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, myMethodHandle); // <-- 2 errors here
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

The errors are:

```
Program.cs(350,13): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCode, byte)' has some invalid arguments
Program.cs(350,35): error CS1503: Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.RuntimeMethodHandle' to 'byte'
```

The `ILGenerator` can `Emit` with a `MethodInfo`, but it doesn't seem to support `MethodHandle`... does anybody know how to get this sample to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so?

```
        MethodInfo writeLine = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] {typeof(string)});
        RuntimeMethodHandle myMethodHandle = writeLine.MethodHandle;
        DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod(
            "HelloWorld",          // name of the method
            typeof(void),          // return type of the method
            new Type[] { },          // argument types for the method
            false);                // skip JIT visibility checks

        ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello, world");
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, writeLine, null);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        // test it 
        Action act = (Action)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
        act();
```

Changes:

- I used a tweaked `GetMethod` to find the `(string)` overload (otherwise it is an ambiguous match)
- use the `MethodInfo`, not the handle (since that is what `ILGenerator` wants)
- use `EmitCall` (the other might have worked too, but I *know* this way works)

Answer (score 0):

Through this library on Nuget.org:
[ClassWrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClassWrapper)

It creates wrappers for types that internally uses dynamically generated methods. So no reflection used (only into the ClassWrapperDescriptor.Load method to generate the dynamic expressions)

Given, e.g. e class named SampleClass

```
//Create the class wrapper descriptor, this can be cached and reused!
var classWrapperDescriptor = new ClassWrapperDescriptor(typeof(SampleClass));
//Initialize the descriptor
classWrapperDescriptor.Load();

//Create the instance of our object
object instance = new SampleClass();

//Create an instance of the wrapper
var classWrapper = classWrapperDescriptor.CreateWrapper(instance);

//Set a property
classWrapper.Set("StringProperty","test");

//Get a property
var stringPropertyValue = classWrapper.Get<string>("StringProperty");

//Invoke a method without return statement
classWrapper.Invoke("ParamMethod", "paramValue");

//Invoke a method witho return statement
var result = classWrapper.Invoke<int>("ReturnMethod", "paramValue");
```

Any feedback on this library is really appreciated!

Comment: ClassWrapper does not even `Load()` my type:
    `var classWrapperDescriptor = new ClassWrapperDescriptor(typeof(MyDataContext));`
    `classWrapperDescriptor.Load(); // throws null reference exception`

Comment: Hi @Don P, can you file a bug on https://github.com/kendarorg/ClassWrapper (or add a comment here) With the definition of the class you are trying to load? Thank you for the help!